# Terraform Databricks automatic installation of libs

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I have few clusters created and I want to install the libraries on them. The catch though is I want these libraries to be installed automatically whenever I create another cluster. Is there a way to do this?

What I am currently doing is this -> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/library

Answer (score 0):

You should to combine combine the `databricks_clusters` data source ([doc](https://data%20%22databricks_clusters%22%20%22all%22%20%7B%20%20%20depends_on%20=%20%5Bdatabricks_mws_workspaces.this%5D%20%7D)) with the `library` resource, something like this (example right from the `library` resource [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/library#installing-library-on-all-clusters)):

```
data "databricks_clusters" "all" {
}

resource "databricks_library" "cli" {
  for_each   = data.databricks_clusters.all.ids
  cluster_id = each.key
  pypi {
    package = "databricks-cli"
  }
}
```